# How do I retrieve editors registered for a certain file extension in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have two editors registered for one file extension and a file with that extension is opened in one of the editors. I now want to open this file programatically in the other editor as well, but without having to know its id. Is it possible to retrieve a list of editors that are registered for one file extension or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Right click on the file you want to edit.  One of the options is "Open with...". Hover the mouse over that option, and you'll get a list of editors registered for that extension.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to open the file programmatically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the editor registry to do this. Get the registry with:

```java
IEditorRegistry registry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry();
```

The registry has a number of methods for finding editors, for example:

```java
IEditorDescriptor [] desc = registry.getEditors("file name");
```

returns the editors that will work on a file name. There are also methods to get the default editor and editors associated with file content types.

The `IEditorDescriptor` contains the editor id which you can pass to open of the `openEditor` methods of `IWorkbenchPage`.

Update:

If you want to open the same file in two editors at the same time you will have to use the version of the `IWorkbenchPage` `openEditor` call which has the 'match flags' option:

```java
public IEditorPart openEditor(final IEditorInput input,
         final String editorId, final boolean activate, final int matchFlags)
```

Specify `IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_NONE` as the `matchFlags` to stop the search for an existing open editor.

Comment: I can only open the file in editor2 if I close editor1 before. Otherwise, nothing happens when I try to open the file in editor2.

Comment: Added the match flags option to use. Note: Eclipse will not coordinate changes made in the two editors.